# Retrieving Transformable of type [String] from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My Core Data attribute is set to Transformable with custom class in Model inspector set as `[String]`

I'm able to save data like this:

```
func saveResultsObjects(results: [String]) {
    let entity   = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "ResultsObjects", in: context)
    let result = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: privateContext)
        
    result.setValue(results, forKey: "results")
        
    do {
        try privateContext.save()
        print("Success Saving In CoreData!")
    } catch {
        print("Failed Saving In CoreData!")
    }
}
```

And trying to retrieve this way:

```
    func getResultsObjects() -> [String] {
        var retrievedResults = [String]()
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ResultsObjects")
        let result = try? privateContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            
            let results = data.value(forKey: "results") as? [String]
            
//            retrievedResults.append(results)
            retrievedResults[0] = "\(String(describing: results))"
        }
        return retrievedResults
    }
```

But getting crash when trying to retrieve on `retrievedResults[0]` with index out of range

I'm saving only `[String]` of `HTML` data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by creating an empty array of String and appending fetched data to it without specifying an index

```
func getResultsObjects() -> [String]? {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ResultsObjects")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    
    var retrievedResults = [String]()
    
    do {
        let result = try privateContext.fetch(request)
        
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            
            guard let results = data.value(forKey: "results") as? [String] else { return nil }
            retrievedResults = results
            
        }
        return retrievedResults
        
    } catch {
        print("Getting Data failed!")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your expected behavior is, but this retrieves the results property from the last fetched item only, because you are not appending anything, though you fetch all entities of ResultsObjects.